# Share folder between Windows and WSL

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using XMing to run Emacs from WSL, which is working quite well. My issue is when trying to share folders between Windows and WSL. I have tried the following:

- Project located in the Windows file system, accessed  via /mnt/ in WSL
- Symlink (created in WSL bash) of project located in the Windows file system
- Copy the project to the WSL file system

Out of the 3 listed options, only the last works with projectile (and likely other Emacs packages). But I need to be able to access/modify the files from Windows as well, so that is not a viable option.

Has anyone found a good solution for this?

Comment: The entire filesystem is already accessible to WSL via `/mnt/[DRIVE_LETTER]`. What are you referring to?

Comment: As mentioned, accessing the files via /mnt/ does not work well with various Emacs packages, such as projectile. I am not sure why, but I would guess it's because of the dual paths ([DRIVE_LETTER]:/folder and /mnt/[DRIVE_LETTER]/folder).

Comment: You could do it the other way around; the WSL home directory is accessible to Windows Explorer.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an option either: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: Create a git repo somewhere and then push and pull patch sets either way?

Comment: You are really pulling teeth here; nothing works?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but I think I had a similar problem with the file systems. I created a symlink in WSL for the [DRIVE_LETTER]->/mnt/[DRIVE_LETTER] to get rid of the 'dual paths' and have the same path for my projects on WSL and Windows

Comment: It seems the issue was related to the fact that the repositories (hg) I tested were cloned using Windows tools. If I clone a repository using WSL (or cygwin, for that matter) to the Windows file system, WSL Emacs/projectile does not seem to have any issues.

This does not quite explain why a repository cloned with Windows tools does not work, or why copying that same repository to the WSL file system solves the issue. But my issues are solved.

Answer (score 11):

One of the advantages of WSL (windows subsystem for Linux) is that you can share files easily with your windows.
I have used the below codes with WSL Ubuntu (but this should work with other versions of Linux as well). Using `/mnt` will do all the magic.

Syntax:- `cd /mnt/drive/Folder/Subfolder`

Sample code:- `cd /mnt/c/Users/Saswat`

Answer (score 7):

I do it so (also to sync between Windows_laptop & Ubuntu_pc):

I have folder "workspace"
and symlinks to it: windows symlink under win and linux symlink under linux.

%USERPROFILE%\Cloud\workspace

for Win usage:
made windows symlink: %USERPROFILE%\workspace -> %USERPROFILE%\Cloud\workspace

for Ubuntu usage (WSL):
made linux symlink: ~/workspace -> /mnt/C/Users/USER/Cloud/workspace

May this help?